# Find two solutions near x=0 of the differential equation $x^2y''-x(1+x)y'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this equation:

$$x^2y''-x(1+x)y'+y=0$$

From this problem I get:

$$p_{1}(x)=-(x+x^2)/x^2\quad\text{and}\quad p_{2}(x)=1/x^2$$

But I'm really having some troubles to advance in this problem. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

Close to $x=0$, you can approximate $x+1 \to 1$. You then obtain a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) of the form
$$x^2 y''- x y'+y =0\,.$$
Plugging in the ansatz $y=x^m$, we see that  $m=1$ is degenerate. The general solution close to $x=0$ thus reads
$$ y(x) = c_1 x + c_2 x \ln x , \qquad x\ll1\,.$$